# Can't dynamically assign JS object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a web app that takes in the names of several people and assigns each one a friend but am running into an issue assigning the friends.

The issue I'm running into is that it properly assigns the first few people friends, but always crashes on the second last person in the array and displays the error message

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'friend' of undefined.

Here is a snippet from my `app.js` code.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

let participantsObject = {};
let participantsArray = [];
let randomNumber;

app.get("/new", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/new.html");
});

app.post("/new", function(req, res) {
  participantsObject[req.body.person] = {};
  participantsArray.push(req.body.person);
  res.redirect("/new");
});

app.get("/setup", function() {
  let size = participantsArray.length;
  let participantsWithoutAGifter = participantsArray;

  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * participantsWithoutAGifter.length)
    participantsObject[participantsArray[i]]["friend"] = participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber];
    participantsWithoutAGifter.splice(randomNumber, 1);
  }

  console.log(participantsObject);

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

And here is my `new.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="person" placeholder="Enter participant name" autofocus>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
      <button type="button"><a href="/setup">Finished</a></button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ideally, it would be able to assign all participants a friend and then log the entire object.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The property selector at `participantsObject[participantsArray[i]]` returns undefined. Please show what values `participantsObject` and `participantsArray` are.

Comment: `participantsObject` and `participantsArray` are populated when someone submits the form associated with `new.html`.

Comment: `participantsWithoutAGifter` sores a link to the original array `participantsArray` and you mutate this array by using `splice`. A mutation of an array that participates in a cycle can be a source of errors. Either create a copy of this array or don't mutate it inside a cycle

Answer (score 1):

The property the loop is trying to select does not yet exist on the `participantsObject`.

Add a check if the property is there. If it is, then assign the `friend` property on the object. And if not, then assign a new object with a `friend` property.

```
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * participantsWithoutAGifter.length);
  let participantsIndex = participantsArray[i];
  if (participantsObject.hasOwnProperty(participantsIndex)) {
    participantsObject[participantsIndex]['friend'] = participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber]
  } else {
    participantsObject[participantsIndex] = {
      friend: participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber]
    }
  }
  participantsWithoutAGifter.splice(randomNumber, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// participantsObject[participantsArray[i]]["friend"] = participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber]; // <-- this will not work

const newProperty = 'friend'
participantsObject[participantsArray[i]] = {
  ...participantsObject[participantsArray[i]],  // <-- so that you don't lose other perperties
  [newProperty]: participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber]
}
```

Alternately you can use Object.assign

```
const newProperty = 'friend'
const source = {}
source[newProperty] = participantsWithoutAGifter[randomNumber]
Object.assign(participantsObject[participantsArray[i]], source )
```

Here is link to code: https://github.com/ApolloTang/stackoverflow-soln--cannot-dyn-assign-js-obj-props/blob/main/app.js